# WPF RoutedUICommand: how to allow to 'type in' a key that is registered as a shortcut?

Tags: .net, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, textinput, routed-commands

I use `CommandBinding` to `RoutedUICommand` in my application extensively. Most of them have keyboard shortcuts which work globally.

For some of the commands, I'd like to have single-key shortcuts, without modifiers - for example, the keypad '+' (`Key.Add`). This all works fine, except that when a text input control (e.g. `TextBox`) is focused, the global Command still takes precedence, consumes the key and doesn't allow it to be typed, executing the command instead. Yet I do want the key to be typed in such circumstances and the command shortcut to be blocked.

Is there a reasonably easy way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

In your CanExecute delegate, call `Keyboard.FocusedElement` property, return false if it is not null. Theoretically, it should work. If it does not work, do it in Execute delegate, and check for this and set e.Handled to false.

Comment: No, both ways don't work. The keypress is consumed even if `CanExecute` signalled false or `Executed` signalled not Handled. (Besides, `Keyboard.FocusedElement` may be legitimately set to many other elements which don't need to process the key; say, `RadioButton`).
A workaround I found so far is to bind the Command in question to the relevant panel or other element (`TabItem` in my case) that does not contain editable fields, rather than to the whole window or Application. This is not a universal solution but may work in most practical cases.